# Selecting a tab in IE using P/Invoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke

IE window can have multiple tabs. I want to use P/Invoke to select a tab with matching title. I already have code which will traverse through all the tabs and check if such tab exists.

Reference P/Inoke: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
 while ((tabNum++ <= 15) &&
               (curChild = FindWindowEx(parentHwnd, curChild, "TabWindowClass", IntPtr.Zero)) != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            String sb = GetWindowTitle(curChild);

            if (sb.Contains(expectedTitleString))
            {
                //TODO : I want to select this tab here.
                foundTab = true;
                break;
            }
            if (is_ie8)
            {
                parentHwnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, parentHwnd, "Frame Tab", IntPtr.Zero);
                curChild = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Presumably you want us to make this work for you - if this is the case then can you at least let us know [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and how it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work in IE9 or IE10, you can't support code like this.

Comment: @Justin : I have tried sending CTRL-T to the IE window, but it doesn't work. I wrote the code you see above and I don't know who would I select this tab.

Comment: @HansPassant: What do you suggest the best way is to control the IE - opening/closing tabs .. changing focus on tabs etc. I have used Watin framework in the past, but it has its own limitations when it comes to tabs.

Comment: IE provides no Automation support for the tabs, although it would be easy to add by Microsoft.  In strongly suspect this is intentional, only the user is in control of what she views.  So the only good way is to not do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting the tab as focused window works?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: IE window - (at least till IE8) has many handles as each control has its own handle. So, this won't work.